# Why no output when executing c program after successfully compiling?

Tags: c, shell, unix

I'm working on a c program about measuring cache size on Ubuntu system. I implement functions in cache.c and invoke them in main.c file. Everything works well. Since the code won't be long, I then move all functions from cache.c to main.c in order to modify code conveniently.

After I compile the main file by typing in gcc -o main main.c, no errors show up. Then I execute the program by command ./main. Nothing happens. What's wrong with my program?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define KB 1024
#define MB 1024 * 1024

int main (int argc, char ** argv[])
{
  static char arr[128 * 1024];
  unsigned int steps = 10000; //4 * 1024 * 1024;
  unsigned int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char);
  clock_t start, end;
  double time_taken;

  // calculate the cache size
  void cache_size()
  { 
    for (int k = 8 * KB; k < size; k+= 8 * KB)
    {
      // count start time
      start = clock();

      for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j += 64)
          arr[j] = 1;

      // count end time
      end = clock();

      // calculate time taken
      time_taken = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

      printf("Test block: %d KB\tTime: %f secs\n", k / KB, time_taken);
    }

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through the code in the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually calling `cache_size`.  You're defining it.  In fact, you're using a compiler specific extension that allows defining one function inside of another.  That's not good practice.

Move the function definition outside of `main`, then call it from inside of `main`.

```
  static char arr[128 * 1024];
  unsigned int steps = 10000; //4 * 1024 * 1024;
  unsigned int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(char);
  clock_t start, end;
  double time_taken;

  // calculate the cache size
  void cache_size()
  { 
    for (int k = 8 * KB; k < size; k+= 8 * KB)
    {
      // count start time
      start = clock();

      for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j += 64)
          arr[j] = 1;

      // count end time
      end = clock();

      // calculate time taken
      time_taken = (double)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

      printf("Test block: %d KB\tTime: %f secs\n", k / KB, time_taken);
    }

    printf("-----------------------------------------------\n");
  }

int main (int argc, char ** argv[])
{
    cache_size();
    return 0;
}
```